# Inrelease and release on spacewalk

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have setup spacewalk for the first time on Ubuntu, but when I try to run `apt-get update` I get an error in concern with inrelease and release files.

1. have created the channels for ubuntu , the package repo is connected http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/.

   If i go to the website I can see the those files, but I cannot import to my server.
2. if i can import the files how can make ubuntu spacewalk client to access the files through spacewalk server.
3. most sites speaks of gpg issue , is there a way i can maybe disable that for my ubuntu clients.

The spacewalk server runs CentOS 07. The client is Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 07. My CentOS 07 can update without spacewalk. The Ubuntu error is

```
Ign:32 spacewalk://spacewalk channels:/main Translation-en
Ign:36 spacewalk://spacewalk channels:/xenial-updates16 Translation-en_ZA
Ign:37 spacewalk://spacewalk channels:/xenial-updates16 Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'spacewalk://spacewalk channels: Release' does not have a Rele                                                                                                 ase file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potential                                                                                                 ly dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                 ils.
```

Comment: Did you read `man apt-secure`?

Comment: @waltinator read the man apt-secure, as my problem is release files, according to man apt-secure i must create the release files on my archive server on this case is centos. is the no command i can copy this file from za.ubuntuarchives because the file exists on this site.